# Delete Rows, Just before Drop table

Tags: mysql

I heard like deleting all rows before dropping table will improve performance. I looked into Web, but couldn't find any reliable answers. Please share whether this is true and the reason behind. Also is the overall performance i.e, ( delete all rows + drop empty table ) is better than dropping table with all rows ?

Comment: @E G Nidheep don't know where you heard it (personally, I have never heard it before) but maybe you confuse it with the use of `TRUNCATE` which has better performance on deleting all rows of a table than `DELETE` as it does not count how many rows are deleted (whereas `DELETE` does). So if you want to empty a table, use the following for better performance `TRUNCATE <table>`, you can also check http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx

Comment: he has a bit of a point.. @dZ.  a `DELETE` can be rolled back in InnoDB a `DROP` table cant so there is less overhead for WAL or better said no WAL is used with `DROP` as in MySQL `DROP` is simply more or less directly mapped to the OS delete dir or file functions..  (comment is oversimplified)  .. **But it is wierd why you would delete all records before dropping the table**..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the clarification, didn't know about it, my answer was only for MySql (due to his tag) where we usually just drop the table, I have never heard or seen anything different. But thanks for the useful notice! :)

Comment: *"my answer was only for MySql (due to his tag) where we usually just drop the table, I"*  i know @dZ. mine comment is also based for MySQL, well MariaDB should also work..  Also the reason why i placed *"But it is wierd why you would delete all records before dropping the table"* in mine comment ... Anyhow it is wierd to do anyway in any RDMS to delete all records before dropping the table well some RDMS support rollbacking a `DROP` aswell but not totally sure how it is implemented there it might work internally might be as  simple as a dir or file rename on disk. ..

Comment: @dZ. I know that TRUNCATE is better than DELETE (if u want to empty the table), thats where all the doubt came, TRUNCATE is like drop the table and CREATE the table again, which is faster than DELETE, then how DELETING all rows before before DROP, will improve DROPS performance.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yeah It's weird.

Comment: I checked, deleting and dropping a table with 1M rows, and Dropping without deleting, Dropping time didn't had much difference. Deleting before dropping is additional expense.

Comment: *"I checked, deleting and dropping a table with 1M rows, and Dropping without deleting, Dropping time didn't had much difference"* It depends if you use innodb one table per file setting, otherwise you delete or beter said mark tables pages in one big file as deleted so they can be reused ..   The one table per file setting should be much faster which uses more disk I/O...

Comment: *"I checked, deleting and dropping a table with 1M rows, and Dropping without deleting, Dropping time didn't had much difference"* Also keep in mind that `DROP` waits ("locks") until other queries and stored programs (triggers/stored procedures) are done on that table or database depening if you did `DROP TABLE/DATABASE`.[source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_table.cc#L1367) behide `DROP TABLE` -> [drop table in parser](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_parse.cc#L3453) .. So that might also increase the execution time..

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all rows before Drop is additional expense. Dropping with and without rows doesn't have much difference. ( tried with 1M rows )